# Generating GPP and NPP from Landsat images using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat, calculate-values

I just started to to use the `GEE` and I want to calculate the annual GPP and NPP from Landsat 8 images. I have spent much time looking for a tutorial on how to do this but all I could find is multiple examples using the MODIS landcover dynamics product and some CONUS data.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[32.1127154838059, 57.21212860835795],
          [32.1127154838059, 55.98450980813724],
          [34.8373248588059, 55.98450980813724],
          [34.8373248588059, 57.21212860835795]]], null, false);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)})
    .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2018-12-31');
    
    
 var calcNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var ndvi = dataset.map(calcNDVI);
var NDVI=ndvi.select('NDVI')



//    var DOY = function(image) {
 //     var date = image.date()
  //    var doy = date.getRelative('day', 'year')
   // }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values are not trivial to compute.  See: https://zslpublications.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/rse2.74

Comment: Thank you @NoelGorelick! I will have a look and try follow the method!